# How to parse request (or end points) to query mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, asp.net-web-api

I am going to to implement a web api like this

```
POST /groups/:groupname/chats/:chatType
```

There could be several groups and each group has at most two chats, a private one or a public one.

Currently, in my /models directory, two related schemas look like this:

```
// group.js
...  
var groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  groupname: {type: String, required: true, index:{unique: true}},
  privateChat: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Chat'},
  publicChat: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Chat'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema)

// chat.js
var chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  chatType: String,  // public or private
  message: [{text: String}]    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Chat', chatSchema);
```

So the question is how can I post a message like "Hello World!" to

```
/groups/boygroup/chats/private
```

...
I have finished the request `GET /groups/:groupname` by `findOne()` method like this:

```
router.get('/groups/:groupname', function(req, res) {
  var groupname = req.body.groupname || req.params.groupname;
  Group.findOne({
    groupname: groupname
  }, function(err, group) {
    if (err)
      return next(err);

    if (!group) {
      res.status(404).send({
        success: false,
        message: "group not found"
      });
    } else {
      res.json(group);
    }
  });
});
```

But I have no idea how to get to a specific chat in a specific group. Maybe my mongoose schema is not good.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I guess I am having trouble understanding your models. Why is `message` an array? Are all chat message going to be inserted into the same document of that Group type?

Comment: Hi@Rob, thanks for asking, temporary yes. I think the answer should be about mongoose population.  I have partly solved this question.